# application hangs at XMLString = client.DownloadString(rootURL + basePolicyNumber);

Tags: c#, http, client, downloadstring

I have two pictures in a directory:

IMG_MGR_VAH007157100_d68807cb-8bd5-4ca8-861d-d878fa7e20b9.tiff
IMG_MGR_VAH007157200_121e8ae3-8e88-4775-be1e-a833e1c1eb51.tiff

I have a button:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check if all files in this folder are .tiff.

            finalImages = Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.FinalPolicyImagesDirectory);

            if (finalImages.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no TIFF files to be uploaded. Please generate files first.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                Web web = new Web();
                XML xml = new XML();

                //The first item in this foreach works fine. The second item gets hung.  
                foreach (string tiffFile in finalImages)
                {
                    PolicyNumber = Path.GetFileName(tiffFile).Substring(8, 12);

                    basePolicyNumber = PolicyNumber.Remove(PolicyNumber.Length - 2);
                    basePolicyNumber = basePolicyNumber + "00";

                    finalPolicyName = Path.GetFileName(tiffFile);

                //THIS IS WHERE I RUN INTO PROBLEMS......BUT ONLY WITH THE SECOND FILE IN THE FOREACH CLAUSE.
                    PolicyUUID = web.GetPolicyUUID(AppVars.pxCentralRootURL, basePolicyNumber);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PolicyUUID) == true)
                    {
                        ixLibraryPolicyBucketURL = AppVars.ixLibraryRootURL + "policy_" + PolicyUUID + "/objects/";

                        try
                        {
                            httpResponse = web.UploadFileToixLibrary(ixLibraryPolicyBucketURL, tiffFile);
                            xml.GeneratePayLoad(ixLibraryPolicyBucketURL + finalPolicyName + ".tiff", finalPolicyName);

                            //web.pxCentralPOST(ixLibraryPolicyBucketURL + "/IMG_MGR_37722779-7487-4d47-a669-ac33a61dceb2.tiff", AppVars.pxCentralRootURL + PolicyUUID, AppVars.pxCentralXMLPayloadFilePath);

                            MessageBox.Show(httpResponse);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
```

The second item in the "foreach" clause gets hung in this call:

PolicyUUID = web.GetPolicyUUID(AppVars.pxCentralRootURL, basePolicyNumber);

Here's the code for this class/method:

```
public string GetPolicyUUID(string rootURL, string basePolicyNumber)
        {
            string PolicyUUID = "";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = AppVars.Username;
                credentials.Password = AppVars.Password;
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                if (DoesPageExist(rootURL + basePolicyNumber) == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                        string XMLString = "";

                        //the app stops working here. it just hangs, no errors or anything. IT WORKS THE FIRST TIME AROUND.
                        XMLString = client.DownloadString(rootURL + basePolicyNumber);

                        doc.LoadXml(XMLString);

                        var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Identifier[@name='InsightPolicyId']");

                        if (node != null && node.Attributes["value"] != null)
                        {
                            var val = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
                            PolicyUUID = val.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Page does not exist. This means that the policy number of the picture you're trying to upload does not exist in pxCentral. Please verify its name. The policy number in questoin is " + basePolicyNumber + ".", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            return PolicyUUID;
        }
```

I'm not sure why while running these codes for the second picture, the app just hangs. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: there is none lol!. if i go through debug, i go line by line and then once i reach XMLString = client.DownloadString(rootURL + basePolicyNumber); nothing happens and the yellow arrow disappears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is happening on network, using Fiddler or similar. Maybe the link is not properly constructed?

Regarding [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

> This method **blocks while downloading the resource**. To download a resource and continue executing while waiting for the server's response, use one of the **DownloadStringAsync** methods.

Comment: im trying to use DownloadStringAsync but it's asking for a "System.URI" as a parameter. I'm trying to use a string. how would I go about passing a string parameter to DownloadStringAsync?